# How to find the dimensions of screen in Flutter Flame Game without Camera?

Tags: flutter, flame

I have a Flame Game app that I want to adjust to make it available on all kinds of screens, but my app doesn't use a world or camera.  All of the solutions that I've found for finding screen size in Flutter seem to use these items.  I don't need a world or camera, but I don't know if there's a way that I can find the screen size without it?

I've tried researching this, but can only find solutions using world or camera.

Answer (score 0):

tYou can get the size of the canvas by just checking the `size` variable in your `FlameGame` class. (`gameRef.size` if you want to use it from a `Component` that has the `HasGameRef` mixin)

There is a built-in camera in the `FlameGame` class if you want to apply a `FixedResolutionViewport`, which sounds like what you want to do? This is the only line you have to add to do that, preferably in your game class's `onLoad` method:

```dart
camera.viewport = FixedResolutionViewport(Vector2(800, 600));
```